# how to implement Vuetify touch prop in the carousel. Thanks

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am facing the propblem with implement touch property on vuetify carousel.
How to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Implement this prop in the v-carousel component (activeSlide must be v-model for v-carousel):

```
:touch="{
    left: () => activeSlide--,
    right: () => activeSlide++
}"
```